# LINQ dictionary to jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

There is a method that returns 2D array, this method querying a dictionary from LINQ query and trying to store keys and values in 2D array.

But I am not able to do that

```
public string[][] GetRecordFields(string selectedRecord)
    {

        var recordFields = (from record in _recordMasterList
                            where record.Item1 == selectedRecord
                            select new 
                            {
                                record.Item2.Keys,
                                record.Item2.Values
                            }).ToArray();
      return recordFields;       
  }
```

But its failed, is there any way?

EDIT: 
Type of `_recordMasterList`

```
List<Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> _recordMasterList;
```

Comment: Can you also include your definition of `Tuple<>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a string array instead of an object in the query, then the `ToArray` will return an array of arrays:

```
public string[][] GetRecordFields(string selectedRecord) {
  return (
    from record in _recordMasterList
    where record.Item1 == selectedRecord
    select new string[] {
      record.Item2.Keys,
      record.Item2.Values
    }
  ).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but its returns 2D array as dimension 1 contains both keys and values and dimension 2 contains nothing.... like string([keys][values],[]); but i want like string([keys],[values])

Comment: @GAPS: In a multi-dimensional array all the data is in the same dimension, so what you want is not possible with a 2D array. If you want it some other way, you have to specify what you mean.

Comment: @GAPS - Do you mean that you want the resulting array to be indexed on the opposite axis? As in: string[2, 50] instead of string[50, 2] ?

Comment: @ Buh Buh no... I want just in simple way. I am having a `List<Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>` so all the dictionaries key and value I want to store in a 2D array. Here the List can have multiple `Tuples` and each `Tuple` have
`Dictionary` so I want ti fetch all dict keys and values

Answer (score 5):

In your `select` you need to create a string array (`new []`). In your example you were creating a new [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

```
public string[][] GetRecordFields(string selectedRecord)
{
    string[][] recordFields = (from record in _recordMasterList
                        where record.Key == selectedRecord
                        select new []
                        {
                            record.Key,
                            record.Value
                        }).ToArray();

    return recordFields;
}
```

(I've changed the code slightly to deal with a `_recordMasterList` of type `Dictionary<string, string>`. Also, in code like this I find it clearer to declare my variable type explicitly, rather than relying on [implicit typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx). That said, with arrays I prefer to use [implicit array typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic16) - `new []` rather than `new string[]`.)

Comment: yes but its returns string([[key][value]],[])... I want as string([keys],[values])

Answer (score 3):

Not a one liner LINQ magic but here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts dictionary to 2d string array
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Dictionary">Dictionary to be converted</param>
/// <returns>2D string Array</returns>
private string[,] ConvertDictionaryTo2dStringArray(Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary)
{
    string[,] stringArray2d = new string[2, Dictionary.Count];
    int i = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Dictionary)
    {
        stringArray2d[0, i] = item.Key;
        stringArray2d[1, i] = item.Value;
        i++;
    }

    return stringArray2d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic version with reversed dimensions:

```
private object[,] Dictionary2Array(Dictionary<object, object> dic)
{
    object[,] arr = new object[dic.Count, 2];
    int i = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> item in dic)
    {
        arr[i, 0] = item.Key;
        arr[i, 1] = item.Value;
        i++;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still a little bit confussing.  Is this the behaviour you are looking for?

(I know that this answer could be optimised a lot, but it seams the easiest way to figue out what you want.)

```
public string[,] GetRecordFields(string selectedRecord)
{
    //List<Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> _recordMasterList;

    List<Dictionary<string, string>> selectedRecords
        = (from record in _recordMasterList
            where record.Item1 == selectedRecord
            select record.Item2)
            .ToList();

    int totalNumberOfRecords = 0;

    foreach(Dictionary<string, string> d in selectedRecords)
    {
        totalNumberOfRecords += d.Count();
    }

    string[,] result = new string[2, totalNumberOfRecords];

    int i = 0;
    foreach(Dictionary<string, string> d in selectedRecords)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in d)
        {
            result[0,i] = kvp.Key;
            result[1,i] = kvp.Value;
            ii++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```